# Overlapping Sections Error which did not come up before

Tags: excel, vba

All of a sudden my code below started throwing an error at me. This is part of a workbook contained inside "module 1". Should I move it to the specific sheet maybe?

Error I receive says: "Cannot use that command on overlapping selections."

```
Sub Test()

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim TradeTable As Excel.ListObject
Set TradeTable = Sheets("Pre Trade").ListObjects("PreTradeTable")

On Error Resume Next
    With TradeTable
        TradeTable.Select
        
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData ' clear possible previous filter
        
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=.ListColumns("Ask Spread").Index, Criteria1:=""
        
        Dim vrg As Range ' Visible Cells Range
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no filtered rows
                Set vrg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData ' this does the trick
        
            If Not vrg Is Nothing Then
                vrg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            End If
    End With
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: What line shows the error? What are you trying to avoid with your **outer** `On Error Resume Next` segment?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: He is trying to hide the error that occurs when selecting a table (`ListObject`). The [ListObject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) doesn't have a `Select` method.

Comment: VBasic2008 is correct which I did not even know I was doing so I removed that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The error shows on the "vrg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp" line

Comment: If you step through is `vrg` nothing or something?

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this behavior: it happens if there is a hidden column. Hidden rows are allowed. To unhide all columns you could use `.DataBodyRange.Columns.Hidden = False` as the first line in the `With` statement.

Comment: VBasic2008 is 100% correct! Thank you!!